# Putting 2 lines of standard input into two different lists

Tags: python, list

so before i ask my question, yes this is a task from college and no I'm not asking for the full solution. I've been stuck on this for a day now and cannot find my answer.

Basically, I'm taking input from sys.stdin.readlines(). I want to put the first line of input into a list called 'x' and the second line of input into a list called 'y'. If there is no input for line 1, leave the list empty and vice versa for the second line of input.

This is what I have at the moment but I get an index out of range error if a second line of input does not exist:

```
import sys
line = sys.stdin.readlines()

i = 0
while i < 1:
   a = line[i].lower().rstrip().split()
   b = line[i+1].lower().rstrip().split()
   i += 1
```

Comment: 1 vote for the confession, made me laugh.

Comment: @Juggernaut Haha you got to be honest.

Comment: are taking user input?

Comment: @Juggernaut yep.

Comment: @KG2005 `readline()` will read a single line and return a string whereas `readlines()` will automatically split the input on newlines and return a list of all the lines. If you want to use `sys.stdin.readlines()`, you could check if the length of the list returned (in your case called `line`) has a length of 2

Comment: @jDo So find the length of standard input, then put each line into a list depending on length?

Comment: @KG2005 E.g. `lines = sys.stdin.readlines(); if len(lines) > 1: a, b = lines[0], lines[1]`

Comment: "@jDo Yeah that's perfect that'll work, that's so simple I've no idea why I didn't think of that. Thanks.

Comment: @KG2005 Cool cool, glad it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Use the builtin `input()` or `raw_input()` if using python2 for taking input from user, then split the input to separate lines and so on.

```
x = []  # For storing first lines
y = []  # For storing second lines


while True:
    lines = raw_input().split('\\n')
    first_line = lines[0] if len(lines) > 0 else None
    second_line = lines[1] if len(lines) > 1 else None
    if first_line:
        x.append(first_line)
    if second_line:
        y.append(second_line)
    print x
    print y
```

Comment: Yeah I understand that solution but in this case, I have to use sys.stdin.readlines(). Thanks though.